# Possible sets of text strings of a given length from a set of letters with repetition

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say we have a set of letters, {5*a, 20*b, 15*c, 7*d). 
This set has a total of 47 letters. 
The required string length is 7.

---

What I would like to calculate is how many sets of length 7 strings are there.

Obviously each set can have 6 strings and 5 remaining letters. one such set would be for example

{aaaaabb,
bbbbbbb,
bbbbbbb,
bbbbccc,
ccccccc,
cccccdd,
ddddd  }

Thank you

Comment: "With repetition" generally means there's an unlimited supply of any letter. Probably "multiset of letters"?

Comment: A naive calculation would be $47!/(7!)^6/5!/6!$ but I'm not sufficiently sure of its correctness.

Comment: @user3834744 I'm not sure what you're asking. Number of ways to split these $47$ letters into $6$ sets of $7$ letters and one set of $5$ letters **or** number of ways one can choose $7$ letters from these $47$ irrespective of order? The latter I would do with [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) or with [stars-and-bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).